# Neo4j high db hits

Tags: neo4j

I'm new to Neo4j and trying to test my queries based on performance.

If I do a simple query like:

```
PROFILE
MATCH (P:User) 
WHERE P.id = 1 
SET P.name = "test" 
Return P, P.name
```

There are 50k user nodes, but for this query, there are 100 009 db hits in 75ms.

For example: this query:

```
MATCH (P1:User {id: "xxx"}) 
MATCH (P2:User {id: "xxx"}) 
MERGE (P1)-[fo:FOL]->(P2) 
on match set P1.fol2 = P1.fol2 -1
on match set P2.fol = P2.fol -1
MERGE (P1)<-[fo1:FOL]-(P2) 
on match set P1.fol = P1.fol -1
on match set P2.fol2 = P2.fol2 -1
MERGE (P1)-[:FRI]-(P2) 
On create set P1.fri= P1.fri +1
on create set P2.fri = P2.fri +1
DELETE fo, fo1
```

This query takes 201015 db hits and 751ms.

Is there a way to make less database hits, because I guess these numbers are way too high?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an index for the property `id` on `User`,

```
CREATE INDEX user_id FOR (n:User) ON (n.id)
```

This should certainly speed your queries